# Migration of Metadata from one Sharepoint Library to another on Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, managed-metadata

I am using Sharepoint Online and I have received the task to set up a library, in which I intend to use metadata for filtering and clustering the documents.
However, chances are that I might have to move the whole library at some point to another Sharepoint.
In that case, it would be great if I could move the files without loosing the metadata that I have attributed to the documents.

I've done some research, but I've only found tools which enable a migration of files including metadata from Sharpoint 2013 to Sharepoint Online. They don't appear to support the kind of migration that I have in mind.

For example:
https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool

Are there any tools out there that could help me in migrating the library within Sharepoint Online?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some methods:

1. Use “save document library as template” with content in library settings, then download the template file, re-upload it as a template in another SharePoint Online site.
2. Use some third party tools like [Sharegate](https://sharegate.com/blog/bulk-copy-your-files-and-folders-without-losing-your-metadata)